# User Bean As Entinty And Just Plain Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

Iam using **spring boot**

I am using **User class** as entity and also as just a bean. How can I configure this **through annotations** so as it can be used as **plain bean** **or an entity like below**

**User**

> As entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my-user")
public class User{
  //property goes here
```

**User**

> As Bean

```
public class User{
      //property goes here
```

is it possible to create an interface than hold

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "my-user")
```

So as whenever I User bean with something @ThisIsAnEntity it mark it as an entity?

Comment: Does it work if you setup `User` with the entity annotations then also create a spring factory `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class to create it as a bean when you want to inject it?

Comment: ok,let me check out